# Is it possible to return more than 1 value/object/array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, return

This code works, but i dont' know if JavaScript correctly execute return'ing more than 1 value. So if in JavaScript it is possible to return a function, maybe it is also possible to return more than 1 value/object/array?

```
function Person (name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

var ageDifference = function(person1, person2) {
    return person1.age - person2.age;
};

function olderAge(person1, person2)
{
    if (person1.age>person2.age) return person1.age;
    else if (person1.age<person2.age) return person2.age;
    else if (person1.age===person2.age) **return person1.age || person2.age;**
}


var alice = new Person("Alice", 30);
var billy = new Person("Billy", 25);

console.log("The older person is " + olderAge(alice, billy));
```

If it is, i wonder (but i think it's stupid) - if i can return switch or if/else statement as well? However i don't think it would make any sense.

Comment: What would you expect to happen when you return more than one value?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. What would it look like if a function returned two values? How would you access them? How would it be different from returning an array of values?

Comment: You can only return one thing from a function. But you can have multiple return statements like you have in your function and just the first `truthy` return statement will execute. Since alice is older than billy `olderAge` will return person1.age. The other two `else if` clauses don't get checked in this example. As Juhana says, just return an array or an object if you want to return multiple things from a function. You can't return switch or if/else statements without wrapping them into a function. But returning a switch statement in a function is the same as returning a value map/array.

Comment: If you were referring to this: `return person1.age || person2.age;` , You are returning 1 value, that `||` in the OR operator. Also, that's wrong on many levels, if the ages are equals *just return one of the two*.

Answer (score 3):

No, strictly speaking you can only return one object/array/value.

If you need to do this you would return an object containing multiple results.

Take this function as an example:

```
var function = testFunction() {
  var a = "some string";
  var b = ['some', 'array'];
  var c = { some: 'object'};

  return {
    itemOne: a,
    itemTwo: b,
    itemThree: c,
  };
};
```

You can then access the results like this:

```
testFunction().itemOne     // returns "some string"
testFunction().itemTwo     // returns ['some', 'array']
testFunction().itemThree   // returns { some: 'object'}
```

Or:

```
var result = testFunction();

result.itemOne             // returns "some string"
result.itemTwo             // returns ['some', 'array']
result.itemThree           // returns { some: 'object'}
```

Comment: In my example code, what if Alice and Billy were both 20 years old and i would like to return just their age (so 20)? How to return common parameter of two or more objects? I mean in my third else if statement, if person1.age and person2.age are the same then return just their age which is common. Should i just "return person1.age;" or "return person2.age;", no matter which one? This wouldn't be clean code :)